# JWPlayer not playing in IE (Doesn't load Flash Player)

Tags: internet-explorer, jwplayer

I am having a problem with JWPlayer in IE 8, that it doesn't open the Flash version in IE. It opens flash version in all the other browsers and opens fine. What happens is that it opens a blank (black colored) player and when it is clicked, Windows media player within IE opens to play the player. It still doesn't play nonetheless.

Somehow in IE, it opens a mp4 version, which, sans surprise, it can't play.

What problem do you think it might have?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have Flash for IE installed.

Comment: It is installed. Definitely. It works for your website.

Comment: Okay, do you have a link we can look at then?

Comment: Is it possible if I could send you through some longtail email? I already sent the email to longtail support which was in my purchase email.

Comment: Sure - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us, I don't recall seeing an email from you today?

Comment: Np, I replied to your email.